# Sql change the result length or time format

Tags: java, sql, oracle

My database is Oracle, and I use navicat to query data.

My code is below:

```
select 

        jzmktr.VPRONAME as jzmktrvproname, 
        jzbid.vproname as jzbidvproname,
        jzbid.vprolocus as jzbidvprolocus,
        jzcur.vname as jzcurvname,
        doc.name as docname,
        zspm.def2 as zspmdef2,
        oa.name as oaname,
        zspm.def6 as zspmdef6,
        zspm.def4 as zspmdef4,
        zpus.def3 as zpusdef3,
        jzbidt.dstartdate as jzbidtdstartdate,
        jzbidt.dcompletedate as jzbidtdconpletedate,
                zspm.def4 as zspmdef4,
        jzcur.PK_GROUP

from JZMKT_REGISTER jzmktr 
left join  JZCU_REGISTER jzcur
on jzcur.PK_REGISTER = jzmktr.pk_customer
left join JZBID_VENDSTART jzbid
on jzmktr.PK_MKTREGISTER = jzbid.PK_MKTREGISTER
left join jzbid_hitbidlog hit 
on hit.pk_vendstart = jzbid.pk_vendstart
left join ZSPM_MAK_EXPLANATION zspm
on zspm.def16 = hit.pk_hitbidlog
left join zspm_pub_uf_singlehead_h zpus 
on zpus.def1 = jzmktr.PK_MKTREGISTER
left join JZBID_TENDERCHK jzbidt 
on jzbidt.pk_vendstart = jzbid.pk_vendstart 
left join bd_defdoc doc 
on doc.pk_defdoc = jzbid.pk_operatetype
left join org_adminorg oa 
on oa.pk_adminorg = zspm.def5
where jzmktr.dr='0' and jzmktr.FSTATUSFLAG='1'
```

You can see the snapshot, this is the `sql` execute result, the time format of `jzbidtdstartdate` and `jzbidtdconpletedate` is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`:

[image]

How can I set the time format to `yyyy-MM-dd` ?

---

**EDIT**

If I change the `jzbidtdstartdate` to :

```
to_char(jzbidt.dstartdate,  'yyyy-MM-dd') as jzbidtdstartdate,
```

I will get this error:

```
on doc.pk_defdoc = jzbid.pk_operatetype  
left join org_adminorg oa   
on oa.pk_adminorg = zspm.def5  
where jzmktr.dr='0' and jzmktr.FSTATUSFLAG='1'  
--and jzmktr.pk_org in (parameter('param3'))  
  --       and substr(jzmktr.dbilldate,1,10)>=parameter('param1')  
    --     and substr(jzmktr.dbilldate,1,10)<=parameter('param2')  
[Err] ORA-01722: invalid number
```

---

**UPDATE**

I search the `jzbidt.dstartdate` in the database, it is `CHAR` type.

Comment: oracle has a to_char function that formats dates.  I don't know what navicat  is, but it might have date formatting functions as well.

Comment: @DanBracuk thanks your reply.

Comment: `jzbidt.dstartdate as to_char(jzbidtdstartdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd')` is invalid SQL. You can't use a function result as a column alias. That should be: `to_char(jzbidt.dstartdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd') as jzbidtdstartdate`

Comment: @a_house_with_no_name you see my post EDIT I have tested it.

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL select clause, change the column from `jzbidt.dstartdate` to `to_char(jzbidt.dstartdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')` to get the date in your required format, assuming it is of a `date` type.

Since it is of `char` type, you only need to do a substring, so `substr(jzbidt.dstartdate, 0,10)` will work fine.

Comment: I am sorry, my friend, it will get error, i use your method, see my EDIT.

Comment: @qg_java: the code you used is not the code from this answer.

Comment: @qg_java is that field (jzbidt.dstartdate) defined as a varchar in the DDL?

Comment: @PradeepPati  It is CHAR.

Answer (score 0):

If your `jzbidt.dstartdate` is `CHAR`, you should convert the `char` to `date`, then format the date:

```
to_char(to_date(jzbidt.dstartdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
```